# Reference and Value types

Tags: vb.net, types, pass-by-reference

I have read that `String` was a "reference type", unlike integers. [MS website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types)

I tried to test its behavior.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim s As New TheTest
    s.TheString = "42"
    Dim z As String = s.GimmeTheString
    z = z & "000"
    Dim E As String = s.TheString
    s.GimmeByref(z)
end sub
Class TheTest
    Public TheString As String
    Public Function GimmeTheString() As String
        Return TheString
    End Function
    Public Sub GimmeByref(s As String)
        s = TheString
    End Sub
End Class
```

So I expected :

1. `z` is same reference as `TheString`, thus `TheString` would be set to "42000"
2. Then `Z` is modified by reference by `GimmeByref` thus `Z` is set to whatever `TheString`  is

Actual result:

1. Z="42000"
2. E="42"
3. TheString="42"

What point am I missing?
I also tried adding "ByRef" in `GimmeByRef` : yes obviously the `GimmeByRef` does work as expected, but it also does if I put everything as Integer, which are said to be "Value type". 
Is there any actual difference between those types?

Comment: Strings are also immutable. If you created a New Class from a ByVal variable, it wouldn't have the value after the method call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion comes about because *regardless of type*, **argument passing in VB is *pass by value* by default**.

If you want to pass an argument by reference, you need to specify the argument type as `ByRef`:

```
Public Sub GimmeByref(ByRef s As String)
```

You also need to understand the difference between mutating a value and re-assigning a variable. Doing `s = TheString` inside the method doesn’t mutate the value of the string, it *reassigns* `s`. This can obviously be done regardless of whether a type is a value or reference type.

The difference between value and reference types comes to bear when modifying the value itself, not a variable:

```
obj.ModifyMe()
```

Strings in .NET are immutable and thus don’t possess any such methods (same as integers). However, `List(Of String)`, for instance, is a mutable reference type. So if you modify an argument of type `List(Of String)`, *even if it is passed by value*, then the object itself is modified beyond the scope of the method.

Comment: Thanks. So the "return TheString" does NOT copy it?

Comment: @Pierre It copies the *reference variable*. But it doesn’t copy the *object* that the reference refers to.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable, every time you do a change it creates a new "reference" like if New was called.

> A String object is called immutable (read-only), because its value
>   cannot be modified after it has been created. Methods that appear to
>   modify a String object actually return a new String object that
>   contains the modification. [Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx#Immutability)

Your code basically does something like this:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim a, b As String

    a = "12"
    b = a
    a = a & "13"

    Console.WriteLine(a) ' 1213
    Console.WriteLine(b) ' 12
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```